# Express routing with a '+' in the path

Tags: node.js, azure, express, angular

I'm using express to host my Angular2 app in Azure.

As per the Angular2 style guide, I've marked some components as lazy loaded by prefixing the folder with a '+'.

When I try to GET a file in this folder (e.g. app/+about/about.component.ts) it returns a 404. However when the '+' is not in the folder name it works.

My Express config for the 'app' folder is `app.use("/app", express.static('app'));`

From looking at the documentation for Express I can see the '+' is used for regex patterns, but couldn't see a way to escape this. What is the workaround?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: path is the folder structure representation so +about can be in path when its folder name is +about and even if its a valid folder name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue:

So I'm building and deploying a nodejs app in Azure by following the instructions as documented [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/node/nodejs-to-azure) and have found the issue is with IIS.

If I look at the logs I can see the error:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

If I add the following to the web.config file then it works ok:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```